# syntax error <?php // login.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Again I have something probably simple for all of you but Im getting

```
syntax error <?php // login.php line one.
```

Then on the javascript I get

```
ReferenceError: ajax is not defined 
ajax.onreadyState = function(){
```

Ive looked at it to long and cant figure it out. I know its just something silly I didnt put in but for the life of me I dont know. If you cant tell I am new at all this lol.

**Html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
    <body>
        <form action="login.php" method="post" id="loginForm">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Login</legend>
        <div><label for="email">Email Address</label><input type="email" name="email" id="email" required></div>
        <div><label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" required></div> 
        <div><label for="submit"></label><input type="submit" value="Login &rarr;" id="submit"></div>   
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <script src="js/login.js"></script>
         <script src="resources/login.php"></script>
         <script src="js/ajax.php"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**login.js**

```
function validateForm() {
    'use strict';
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var password = document.getElementById('password');
    if ( (email.value.length > 0) && (password.value.length > 0)) {
        var ajax = getXMLHttpRequestObject();
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('Please complete the form!');
        return false;
    }
}
function init() {
    'use strict';
    if (document && document.getElementById) {
        var loginForm = document.getElementById('loginForm');
        loginForm.onsubmit = validateForm;
    }
}
window.onload = init;
ajax.onreadyState = function(){
    if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
        if ( (ajax.status > 200 && ajax.status < 300)
        || (ajax.status == 304) ) {
        if (ajax.responseText == 'VALID') {
            alert('You are now logged in!');
        } else {
            alert('The submitted values do not match those on file!');
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
    } // End of status IF-ELSE.
} // End of readyState IF.
ajax.open('POST', 'resources/login.php', true);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
var data = 'email=' + encodeURIComponent(email.value) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(password.value);
ajax.send(data);
return false;
}; // End of function assignation.`
```

**login.php**

```
<?php // login.php
if ( isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])
&& ($_POST['email'] == 'test@example.com')
&& ($_POST)['password'] == 'securepass') ) {
    ehco 'VALID';
} else {
    echo 'INVALID';
}
?>
```

Comment: You want `onreadystatechange` not `onreadystate`.

Comment: Why are you including your **PHP** login page as a script? : `<script src="resources/login.php"></script>`

Comment: In the login php i see `ehco 'VALID' `. Don't think it fixes your problem but still ^^

Comment: @Heather I think you have a lot of errors. but according to you error I have giving you the answer.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ as far as I can see, all answers at this point all point out valid errors!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax error is coming from this line:

```
<script src="resources/login.php"></script>
```

When you load in this, your browser will be expecting javascript and will only get `INVALID` echoed back, which of course is not valid javascript. Comment out that line and fix the other typos pointed out in other answers and it might just run!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])
&& ($_POST['email'] == 'test@example.com')
&& ($_POST['password'] == 'securepass')) {
         ^^^ you have one extra closing bracket here
```

And also have the wrong spelling of `ehco 'VALID';` this should be `echo 'VALID';`

check the above code and replace in you code.

Answer (score 0):

You have `ehco` instead of `echo` at `ehco 'VALID';` and `&& ($_POST)['password'] == 'securepass') )` This line is wrong. should be: `&& ($_POST['password'] == 'securepass') )`

Answer (score 0):

You variable ajax is defined in a localscope, it is not available where you are using it. And there is no `onreadyState` event.